# Is Morgoth "working as intended" by Illuvatar's will?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, morgoth

If all beings, regardless of their good-evil alignment, can find the cause and origin of all things to lie ultimately in Illuvatar, then can it be said that Morgoth - and other Ainur who went rogue - are ultimately acting by Illuvatar's will, and therefore will have a place in the Second Music and in Arda Reborn?

Comment: Just because someone can be said to be "working in accord with the will of Eru" doesn't necessarily mean that they will have a place in the Second Music.

Comment: "And thou, Melkor, shalt see that no theme may be played that hath not its uttermost source in me, nor can any alter the music in my despite. For he that attempteth this shall prove but mine instrument in the devising of things more wonderful, which he himself hath not imagined."